# How to verify whether user has already signed In or not in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm right now tinkering with flutter_auth, but now I'm searching for a way to check whether a user has already signed in or not before.

Example: User sign's In and after a couple of minutes he uninstalls and somehow reinstalls the app and here I want to check whether the user has already signed In before or not.

I searched for documents but ended up with none, it would be nice if I get the documentation or implementation instructions

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if a user exists in Firebase Authentication with a specific email address, you can use the [`fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` method](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/fetchSignInMethodsForEmail.html). As its documentation says:

> Returns a list of sign-in methods that can be used to sign in a given user (identified by its main email address).
>
> This method is useful when you support multiple authentication mechanisms if you want to implement an email-first authentication flow.
>
> An empty List is returned if the user could not be found.

Comment: well, it shows an empty list even though I have signed in with that email before,
this is my implementation

`FirebaseAuth _delegate = FirebaseAuth.instance;`
`List<String> signInMethods = _delegate.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email);`
`